# Add action in ionic2 notifications buttons

Tags: ionic-framework, notifications, ionic2

I'm trying to build an ionic2 application which send some guidance notifications to users,i want to send the user to a specific page when he click on the notification and not the homepage.
Here is my code:

```
public schedule(title, text) {
        LocalNotifications.schedule({
            title,
            text,
            at: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1* 1000)    

        });
    }


LocalNotifications.on("click", (notification, state) => {

            let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: this.todos[this.num].info.nom_du_musee,
                subTitle: this.todos[this.num].info.periode_ouverture+" "+this.todos[this.num].info.adr+"  site web  "+this.todos[this.num].info.sitweb,
                buttons: ["OK"]
            });
            alert.present()
        });




  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a handler to the button as per https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: this.todos[this.num].info.nom_du_musee,
    subTitle: this.todos[this.num].info.periode_ouverture+" "+this.todos[this.num].info.adr+"  site web  "+this.todos[this.num].info.sitweb,
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'OK',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('OK clicked');
        }
      }
    ]
});

alert.present()
```

The next stage is to replace the console.log with the code to push the new page ..

```
this.navCtrl.push(DestinationPage);
```